# Retrieving information from Jboss AS vault in camel route

Tags: apache-camel, jboss-eap-6

I am storing sensitive information like password, APIKey etc in JBoss AS vault.I need to retrieve it in camel route and set camel exchange headers.

I tried in below it is not working.

```
 <setHeader headerName="apikey">
      <simple>{{VAULT::event_policy_online::password::1}}</simple>
  </setHeader>
```

how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an EAP system property (for example, `myfusepassword`) for the password you created in the vault.
Then the password can be accessed in the camel configuration by using the following notation:

```
${sys.myfusepassword}
```

Comment: I tried the above suggestion It is retrieved as null,also i wanted to use the property files instead of system properties.

Comment: Thanks i found the same solution in redhat article and i realised i had given the property name with sys. while creating properties,after fixing it is working fine now.

Comment: How can i supply the password in from URI,it is not taking if i supply as  ${sys.esb.source.sftpPwd}.  <from id="Endpoint" uri="sftp:{{esb.source.sourceFtpHostname}}:22/{{esb.source.directoryName}}?siteCommand=NAMEFMT 1&amp;stepwise=false&amp;fileName={{esb.source.fileName}}&amp;password=${sys.esb.source.sftpPwd}&amp;username={{esb.source.sourceFtpUname}}&amp;useList=false&amp;delete=true&amp;delay={{esb.source.pollingDelay}}&amp;streamDownload=true"/>